SImple Harmonic Motion blur removal
I have an image with lots of point sources and there looks like a motion blur in one axis, with point sources being transformed into hourglass shape. I presume this is due to a vibration in the image where the period is short compared to the exposure.
I've only a single frame to work with for each image.
Removing standard motion blur in a single known direction is just a deconvolution with a given filter, but does anyone know of a good way to solve this problem?

Welcome to the stackexchange for CG! For your question, I think it would be clearer if you can post that motion-blurred image.
